# What does Error 1 Local variable 'USD' is already declared in the current block mean in my program?

Tags: vb.net

I've revised my code several times in an attempt to write a currency conversion program that will tell the exchange rate from US dollars to canadian or mexican as follows and I keep getting the error:

```
Error 1 Local variable 'USD' is already declared in the current block. C:\Users\dgrossi0914\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Program3\Program3\Program3\Form1.vb 9 13 Program3

My code is as follows:

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub US_Dollar_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles US_Dollar.TextChanged
        Const Canadian_Dollar As Decimal = 1.13
        Const Mexican_Peso As Decimal = 11.03
        Dim US_Dollar As String = 1.0
        Dim USD As Single 'makes USD member of Single
        Decimal.TryParse(US_Dollar, USD)
        ConRate.Text = Val(USD.Text) * Val(Canadian_Dollar) 'helps with constant
        Dim USD As Single 'makes USD member of Single
        US_Dollar = Convert.ToString(USD)
        ConRate = Val(USD.Text) * Val(Mexican_Peso) 'helps with constant
        US_Dollar = Format(1, "$0.00")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConRate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConRate.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Canadian_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Canadian_Dollar.Click
        ConRate.Text = US_Dollar.Text & " U.S._Dollar(s) " & " equal " & Val(US_Dollar.Text) * Val(Canadian_Dollar.Text) & " Canadian Dollars"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Mexican_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Mexican_Peso.Click
        ConRate.Text = US_Dollar.Text & " U.S._Dollar(s) " & " equal " & Val(US_Dollar.Text) * Val(Mexican_Peso.Text) & " Mexican Pesos"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClrButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClrButton.Click
        US_Dollar.Text = ""
        ConRate.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub XitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles XitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've tried the book, which helped with some of it, I watched all the tutorials, and I tried looking for examples on the internet.

However, the book does help much with this problem, there are no tuturials like this, and I paid to joined learnvideostudio.net there, but it does let me ask a question.

With that said do you have any better advise than what they recommend for solving this problem because I think my instructor is trying to tell me to use Dim USD As Single twice. Once before the parse and the other before the convert tco string, which gives me the error mentioned above. Howeveer, if I removed the second Dim USD As Single then I get the error USD not a member of Single.

What should I do?

Comment: Seems obvious. You have `Dim USD` twice in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty much self-descriptive. There is a variable declared more than once, and in fact it's actually correct. This line is copied twice in the `US_Dollar_TextChanged` method:

```
Dim USD As Single 'makes USD member of Single
```

Just delete the last one and it will work. I don't understand the error you get if you removed it, but to begin with delete the second line, then read the exact message you get afterwards.